# Inserting a div into wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, html, menu, insert

I'm trying to add a div to my navigation menu in wordpress. wp_nav_menu loads all menu items but I have no idea how to add a div into the structure. My goal is to have a submenu pop up on menu-item hover, and to have an arrow image on top of the submenu block to make it look like a square text-balloon. I know how to get it where I want it and everything, but not how to get the div in there.

Right now, looks something like this

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>
  <a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
     <a>
```

And I want it to look like this

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>
  <a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <div class="pointer">
     <li>
      <a>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a Walker Class. Add this in your functions.php file:

```
class Walker_Nav_Pointers extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
        $output .= "\n<div class=\"pointer\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n".($depth ? "$indent</div>\n" : "");
    }
}
```

And then wherever you're calling your nav menu, add this to the existing arguments:

```
<?php
$navArgs = array('walker' => new Walker_Nav_Pointers());
wp_nav_menu($navArgs);
?>
```

The above example is untested and I can't guarantee it will work straight out of the gate, but it should get you started.

More information on [WP Nav Menus Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and some information on [Adding Custom Walkers Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039).